# Visual Studios - Share folders between different projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0, filesystems, shortcut

I've got two projects, one CF2.0 project and one NET2.0 project. These projects are related to a CF2.0 application project and a NET2.0 WebService project respectively.

The projects are my Data Access Layers and they are both identical, apart from the ProtoBuf Dll version.

Is there any way that my NET2.0 DAL project can just reference the folders in my CF2.0 project without having to copy over all 500 or so source files? I'm sure I've seen this done before where a shortcut is just added to a file and then the project compiles the referenced file.

I am using Visual Studios 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is indeed possible to add a link to a file instead of copying it, but this is only possible with files, not with folders.

Cant' you just reference the compiled DAL?

Comment: Worked it out: Add New Existing Item, Add Link